# Cannot implicitly convert type, an explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I've set up a ViewModel (was previously using a ViewBag) but I've encountered an error in the following code, I've researched it but haven't personally been able to figure out my issue:

```
public ActionResult Index(string category, string search)
    {
        ProductIndexViewModel viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel();
        var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Category);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(search) ||
                    p.Description.Contains(search) ||
                    p.Category.Name.Contains(search));

            viewModel.Search = search;

        }

        viewModel.CatsWithCount = from matchingProducts in products
                                  where matchingProducts.CategoryID != null
                                  group matchingProducts by
                                  matchingProducts.Category.Name into
                                  catGroup
                                  select new CategoryWithCount()
                                  {
                                      CategoryName = catGroup.Key,
                                      ProductCount = catGroup.Count()
                                  };

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
           products = products.Where(p => p.Category.Name == category);
        }

        viewModel.Products = products;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The error occurs down the bottom in the line:

```
viewModel.Products = products;
```

The exact error is

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<OnlineStore.Models.Product>'` to
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<OnlineStore.ViewModels.ProductIndexViewModel>'`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I'm very new to using Visual Studio and was just wanting to know what I would have to do to fix this error.

EDIT:

ProductIndexViewModel:

`````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OnlineStore.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductIndexViewModel
    {
        public IQueryable<ProductIndexViewModel> Products { get; set; }
        public string Search { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CategoryWithCount> CatsWithCount { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CatFilterItems
        {
            get
            {
                var allCats = CatsWithCount.Select(cc => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = cc.CategoryName,
                    Text = cc.CatNameWithCount
                });
                return allCats;
            }
        }
    }
    public class CategoryWithCount
    {
        public int ProductCount { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CatNameWithCount
        {
            get
            {
                return CategoryName + " (" + ProductCount.ToString() + ")";
            }
        }
    }
}````
`````

Comment: This error doesnt quite make sense, what is the actual type of `ProductIndexViewModel.Products` ?

Comment: viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel(); while products = db.Products  Products != ProductIndexViewModel.  Avoid using "var" unless necessary.  All it does is make it hard to find errors.  You move errors that can be found during compiling to run-time errors that are harder to figure out.

Comment: @Oskar Ahleberg, Please add your `ProductIndexViewModel` to the question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, Added

Comment: 'viewModel.Products = products.tolist()' try this

Comment: It is clear from your code that the `Products` property is of type `IQueryable<nlineStore.ViewModels.ProductIndexViewModel>` but you are trying to assign it `IQueryable<OnlineStore.Models.Product>` That's why you are getting this error. `ProductIndexViewModel` and `Product` are two different classes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my ProductIndexViewModel class. I had

```
public IEnumerable<ProductIndexViewModel> Products { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Thank you to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Products` seem wrong in the `ProductIndexViewModel` class

```
public class ProductIndexViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<ProductIndexViewModel> Products { get; set; }
```

---

1. `Products` is an `IQueryable`, which doesn't really make sense, and probably should be a `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`

**Example**

```
public List<ProductIndexViewModel> Products { get; set; }
```

---

2. The generic parameter looks wrong, it likely should be `Product` or some ViewModel like `ProductViewModel` in the case of a ViewModel you will need to `Select`/Project to it

---

3. You should probably be calling, `ToList` on the results

**Example**

```
viewModel.Products = products.ToList();
```